# UiTableview not appearing on screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

For some reason my tableview doesn't show up at all even though every other element does. I tried the same code on a different project and it showed up perfectly.

Here are my tableview functions:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("this will run")

    return 3
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell

    cell.otsikko.text = "example"
    cell.kuvaus.text = "exampledesc"

    print("this code won't run")

    return cell
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

And here's some other cell setup:

```
class Cell : UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var otsikko: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var kuvaus: UITextView!
}

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

Image of the storyboard:

[image: Storyboard]

Image of the run application:

[image: Run app]

So, as you can see, it sort of skips the whole tableview and won't generate the cells. It could be about layouts and constraints, but honestly I have no idea.

Comment: Are you sure you've set the data source of your table view to be the view controller?

Comment: are you using autolayouts?

Comment: Yes @Ali I'm using auto layouts, thanks for replying!

Comment: @Moe Abdul-Hameed yes, I've set them both via storyboard and programmatically to be sure. Thanks for replying!

Comment: Anyone? Please I need help :D

Answer (score 1):

I think, first step would be to check your viewcontroller for outlets, and 
set datasource and delegate.

```
override func viewDidLoad {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   tableView.delegate = self
   tableView.datasource = self
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have connected the tableview to the view controller. Thanks for replying!